# Windows deleted my uTorrent.exe file - not listed in W Defender

Tags: windows-10, utorrent, windows-defender

I was surprised yesterday when I tried to run uTorrent and the .exe file was missing. I looked up in Windows Defender quarantine and deleted files but it was not listed.

It has been a month or so that I last run uTorrent, maybe W Defender clears the deleted files list after some N days? **I would like to find out what and when** deleted the software exe.

Comment: Windows will give you a notification when it deletes the file. If you pay attention to those notifications and you did not see it, it was not windows defender that removed the file.

Comment: You sure the exe is not a hidden file? Have you unhidden hidden files in folder options?

Comment: Yes I'm. I installed the latest version now..